# Cannot access EJB jar within an ear

Tags: java, deployment, gradle, ejb, wildfly

My ear structure is as follows:

```
XYZ.ear
    |
    |------------- lib
    |-------------META-INF
    |--------------firstEJB.jar
    |--------------app.war
```

When I am trying to deploy the XYZ.ear, I am not able to access classes in firstEJB.jar. I am getting followint error when trying to deploy:

```
15:49:24,583 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."XYZ.ear"."app.war".POST_MODULE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."XYZ.ear"."app.war".POST_MODULE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment "app.war" of deployment "XYZ.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sial.ecommerce.core.init.DeepInit from [Module "deployment.XYZ.ear.app.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.checkDeclaredApplicationClassAsServlet(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:292)
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.scanWebDeployment(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:154)
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.deploy(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:105)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.0.0.Final.jar:8.0.0.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sial.ecommerce.core.init.DeepInit from [Module "deployment.XYZ.ear.app.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134) [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsScanningProcessor.checkDeclaredApplicationClassAsServlet(JaxrsScanningProcessor.java:290)
```

DeepInit class is a class in firstEJB.jar.

When I try to add firstEJB.jar inside lib directory, it is showing some beanmanager related issues, since it contains ejbs. So I tried to put this jar outside lib directory, after going through this link:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly.

I am using build.gradle to build the EAR.My build.gradle is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral(); 
        maven {
            url "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/"
        }
    }

    configurations {
        compile
        testCompile
        testRuntime
        jacoco
    } 

    dependencies { 
        classpath 'org.ajoberstar:gradle-jacoco:0.3.0'
    }  
}

allprojects {
    group = 'com.sial.ecommerce'
    version = ''


    repositories {
        mavenCentral();
        maven {
            url "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/"
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'jacoco';

    apply plugin: 'ear'

    dependencies {
        deploy project(path:':app', configuration: 'archives');
        deploy project(path:':firstEJB', configuration: 'archives');


    }

    ear {
        version = "";

        archiveName ="XYZ.ear";

        appDirName 'EarContent'

        duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE;
        caseSensitive = true;

        rootSpec.exclude("**/activation-1.1.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/asm*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/jboss-*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/org.jacoco*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/wildfly-*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/hibernate-*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/gradle-*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/cdi-*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/org.osgi.*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/serializer-*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/arquillian-*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/resteasy-*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/guava-*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/jackson-jaxrs-*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/jackson-core-asl-*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/jackson-mapper-asl-*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/reflections-*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/metrics-core-*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/servo-core-*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/aspectjweaver-*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/javax.json-*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/jaxrs-api-*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/javax.mail-*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/validation-api-*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/javassist-*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/dom4j-*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/annotations-*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/javax.inject-*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/xalan-*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/el-api-*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/jsr250-api-*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/xml-apis-*.jar");
        rootSpec.exclude("**/slf4j-api-1.7.6.jar");
    }
}
```

My application.xml in META-INF looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/application_7.xsd" id="Application_ID" version="7">
  <display-name>ABC</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>app.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>app</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
      <ejb>myfirstEJB.jar</ejb>
    </module>
</application>
```

One more issue I noticed is that, for deployment the server is searching for files from:

C:\Apps\wildfly8.0.0.Final\bin directory

```
ERROR com.sial.ecommerce.core.init.DeepInit - C:\Apps\wildfly-8.0.0.Final\bin\src\test\resources\xml\con\con.json (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

DEEPInit class is a class in myfirstEJB.jar.

instead of

C:\Apps\wildfly-8.0.0.Final\standalone\deploments directory(where our ear is present).

Can someone help me to build and deploy a proper ear so that classes in firstEJB.jar can be accessed?

Comment: Thank you all. Actually my issue is solved. The issue was with the EAR which i build using gradle, which is   an archive. So we have to extract it. After extracting it is deploying properly.
The problem with archive EAR was that it is taking the default path as C:\Apps\wildfly8.0.0.Final\bin directory . So it wont work. When we change to exploded EAR it is taking the ear from C:\Apps\wildfly-8.0.0.Final\standalone\deploments directory.

Comment: I don't exactly follow.  EAR's are typically deployed packaged up in a JAR (well, EAR) file...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look's like class com.sial.ecommerce.core.init.DeepInit trying to read local resource using  code like this:

```
new File(".\src\test\resources\xml\con\con.json");
```

If it's true, replace this code with:

```
com.sial.ecommerce.core.init.DeepInit.getResource("xml\con\con.json");
```

Comment: thank you... No that was not the case. the jar containing DeepInit was missing. Now its solved

Answer (score 0):

try setting the "ear-subdeployments-isolated" property of the EE-subsystem in wildfly config to false:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0" >            
  <ear-subdeployments-isolated>false</ear-subdeployments-isolated>
</subsystem>
```

If this setting is set to true (which is the default afaik) then you would have to declare a dependency from your war to the jar:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Class+Loading+in+WildFly

Comment: Ya it is setted to false only. Still the same issue

Comment: Can you post a bit more of the contents of your ear? How does the meta-inf folder look like? Your jar and war...

Comment: sure. I added appilcation.xml